# Can I assign an SVG class name from a variable

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'd like to assign an SVG class from a variable. For instance:`.attr('class', lineCount)`, where `lineCount` is a string variable generated elsewhere. Basically, it would translate to `.attr('class', '1')` or `.attr('class', '2')` or so on.

I'd then like to be able to `selectAll` of the elements of that class. For example `.selectAll(lineCount)`...basically translating to `selectAll('.1')` or `selectAll('2')`.

Can I use a variable to assign the class? If so how? And how would I `selectAll` with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variable is:

```
var lineCount = "someClass";
```

Set the class using:

```
.attr("class", lineCount)
```

Then, for selecting, you have to concatenate two strings: your variable and the class selector (`.`).

```
selectAll("." + lineCount)
```

Have in mind that you **cannot** start a class name with a number. So, instead of using "1", "2" and so on for the class name, as in your question, you could use "class1", "class2" and so on.